# I need help understanding what Exercise 5-12 is asking for in the C Programming Language book

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie, tabstop

> `K&R C Programming Language: pg. 105`
>
> Extend `entab` and `detab` to accept the shorthand
>
> `entab -m +n`
>
> to mean tab stops every `n` columns, starting at column `m`.

`entab` replaces a number of spaces with a tab character and `detab` does the opposite. The question I have concerns the tab stops and `entab`. I figure that for `detab` it's pretty easy to determine the number of spaces needed to reach the next tab stop, so no worries there. With `entab`, replacing spaces with tabs is slightly more difficult since I cannot for sure know how large the tab character goes to its own tab stop (unless there is a way to know for sure).

Am I even thinking about this thing properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"tab stops every n columns, starting at column m" tells you how large each tab stop is, at least by my reading: it's just *n*. Only the first tab stop is different; that one is *m*.

Comment: So don't worry about `entab` because `\t` will go to whatever tabstop it wants to?

Comment: @marsol0x For the case you're thinking of, I think you're meant to *input* the length of `\t` as *n*, where *m* = 0. With *m* and *n* you are specifying to `entab` what the tab stop behavior of your system is.

Answer (score 2):

entab needs to work out when runs of spaces reach a tabstop - then that run of spaces can be replaced by a tab character.

For example, the following line of text (the ruller is there for reference):

```
           1   1   2   2   2
1      8   2   6   0   4   8
-------+---+---+---+---+---+
          this     is a line
```

should look like the following after `entab -8 +4`:

```
\t  this \tis a line
```

(note that it might be reasonable for there to be two tab characters following 'this' in the line, since either a space or a tab would reach that particular tab stop).